# Unable to Select Option From Option Set Produced Dynamically by Javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I am dynamically populating a custom option set field with all D365 entities with the following code:

```
// This function is called when the form loads
function OnLoad(executionContext) {
    debugger;
    var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();

    // Get the optionset field on the form
    var optionSetField = formContext.getAttribute("zzz_entity");

    // Call the function to get entity names
    GetEntityNames().then(function(entityNames) {
        // Clear the options
        optionSetField.controls.forEach(function(control) {
            control.clearOptions();
        });

        // Add new options
        for (var i = 0; i < entityNames.length; i++) {
            var option = {
                text: entityNames[i],
                value: i + 1
            };

            // Add option without checking controls
            optionSetField.controls.forEach(function(control) {
                control.addOption(option);
            });
        }
    });
}

// This function retrieves all entity logical names
function GetEntityNames() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("GET", Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext().getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.0/EntityDefinitions?$select=LogicalName", true);
        req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
        req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
        req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState === 4) {
                req.onreadystatechange = null;
                if (this.status === 200) {
                    var results = JSON.parse(this.response);
                    var entityNames = results.value.map(function(entity) {
                        return entity.LogicalName;
                    });
                    resolve(entityNames);
                } else {
                    reject(new Error('Request failed with status: ' + this.status + ', Status Text: ' + this.statusText));
                }
            }
        };
        req.send();
    });
}
```

This code works in that the option set is successfully being populated. However, when I select an option, it doesn't successfully select and the field is not populated.

Is there something missing from my code? An extra eye would help.

**EDIT per commentor request:**

The following is the rendered HTML (shortened the option list values due to character limit in question):

```
<div id="zzz_entity" data-attributename="zzz_entity" data-formid="59c9aade-4c73-4248-a8e4-d1b44a10f870" data-fdeid="PrimaryEntity" data-layout="0" tabindex="1040" data-picklisttype="1" class="ms-crm-Inline-Chrome picklist nvarchar" title="Select to enter data" aria-label="Entity  Entity Select the Enter key to edit">
    <div class="ms-crm-Inline-Value ms-crm-Inline-NoValue" style="display: block;">
        <label data-for-id="zzz_entity_label" id="Entity_label" class="dummy-optionsetClass"><div class="ms-crm-div-NotVisible">Entity</div></label><span></span>
    </div><div class="ms-crm-Inline-Edit ms-crm-Inline-OptionSet noScroll" style="display: none;" id="zzz_entity_iDiv" aria-label="Entity"><select id="zzz_entity_i" class="ms-crm-SelectBox ms-crm-Inline-OptionSet-AutoOpen ms-crm-Inline-HideByZeroHeight-Ie7" aria-labelledby="zzz_entity_w" attrname="zzz_entity" size="10" style="height: 102px;"><option title="" value="-1"></option><option title="aaduser" value="1">aaduser</option><option title="account" value="2">account</option><option title="accountleads" value="3">accountleads</option><option title="aciviewmapper" value="4">aciviewmapper</option><option title="actioncard" value="5">actioncard</option><option title="actioncardusersettings" value="6">actioncardusersettings</option><option title="actioncarduserstate" value="7">actioncarduserstate</option><option title="activityfileattachment" value="8">activityfileattachment</option><option title="activitymimeattachment" value="9">activitymimeattachment</option><option title="activitymonitor" value="10">activitymonitor</option><option title="activityparty" value="11">activityparty</option><option title="activitypointer" value="12">activitypointer</option><option title="adminsettingsentity" value="13">adminsettingsentity</option><option title="advancedsimilarityrule" value="14">advancedsimilarityrule</option><option title="adx_externalidentity" value="15">adx_externalidentity</option><option title="adx_invitation" value="16">adx_invitation</option><option title="adx_invitation_invitecontacts" value="17">adx_invitation_invitecontacts</option><option title="adx_invitation_mspp_webrole_powerpagecomponent" value="18">adx_invitation_mspp_webrole_powerpagecomponent</option><option title="adx_invitation_redeemedcontacts" value="19">adx_invitation_redeemedcontacts</option><option title="adx_inviteredemption" value="20">adx_inviteredemption</option><option title="adx_kbarticle_kbarticle" value="21">adx_kbarticle_kbarticle</option><option title="adx_portalcomment" value="22">adx_portalcomment</option><option title="adx_setting" value="23">adx_setting</option><option title="adx_webformsession" value="24">adx_webformsession</option><option title="aiplugin" value="25">aiplugin</option><option title="aipluginexternalschema" value="26">aipluginexternalschema</option><option title="aipluginexternalschemaproperty" value="27">aipluginexternalschemaproperty</option><option title="aiplugininstance" value="28">aiplugininstance</option><option title="aipluginoperation" value="29">aipluginoperation</option><option title="aipluginoperationparameter" value="30">aipluginoperationparameter</option><option title="aipluginusersetting" value="31">aipluginusersetting</option><option title="annotation" value="32">annotation</option><option title="annualfiscalcalendar" value="33">annualfiscalcalendar</option><option title="appaction" value="34">appaction</option><option title="appaction_appactionrule_classicrules" value="35">appaction_appactionrule_classicrules</option><option title="appactionmigration" value="36">appactionmigration</option><option title="appactionrule" value="37">appactionrule</option><option title="appactionrule_webresource_scripts" value="38">appactionrule_webresource_scripts</option><option title="appconfig" value="39">appconfig</option><option title="appconfiginstance" value="40">appconfiginstance</option><option title="appconfigmaster" value="41">appconfigmaster</option><option title="appelement" value="42">appelement</option><option title="applicationfile" value="43">applicationfile</option><option title="applicationuser" value="44">applicationuser</option><option title="applicationuserprofile" value="45">applicationuserprofile</option><option title="applicationuserrole" value="46">applicationuserrole</option><option title="appmodule" value="47">appmodule</option><option title="appmodulecomponent" value="48">appmodulecomponent</option><option title="appmodulecomponentedge" value="49">appmodulecomponentedge</option><option title="appmodulecomponentnode" value="50">appmodulecomponentnode</option><option title="appmodulemetadata" value="51">appmodulemetadata</option><option title="appmodulemetadatadependency" value="52">appmodulemetadatadependency</option><option title="appmodulemetadataoperationlog" value="53">appmodulemetadataoperationlog</option><option title="appmoduleroles" value="54">appmoduleroles</option><option title="appnotification" value="55">appnotification</option><option title="appointment" value="56">appointment</option><option title="appsetting" value="57">appsetting</option><option title="appusersetting" value="58">appusersetting</option><option title="archivecleanupinfo" value="59">archivecleanupinfo</option><option title="archivecleanupoperation" value="60">archivecleanupoperation</option><option title="asyncoperation" value="61">asyncoperation</option><option title="attachment" value="62">attachment</option><option title="attribute" value="63">attribute</option><option title="attributeimageconfig" value="64">attributeimageconfig</option><option title="attributemap" value="65">attributemap</option><option title="attributemaskingrule" value="66">attributemaskingrule</option><option title="audit" value="67">audit</option><option title="authorizationserver" value="68">authorizationserver</option><option title="availabletimes" value="69">availabletimes</option><option title="availabletimesdatasource" value="70">availabletimesdatasource</option><option title="azureserviceconnection" value="71">azureserviceconnection</option></select></div><span class="ms-crm-Inline-LockIcon" id="zzz_entity_lock" style="display: none;"><img src="/_imgs/imagestrips/transparent_spacer.gif" class="ms-crm-ImageStrip-inlineedit_locked" alt="Locked control"></span><span class="ms-crm-Inline-fieldChangeIndicatorIcon" id="zzz_entity_fieldChangeIndicatorImage" style="visibility: hidden;"><img src="/_imgs/imagestrips/transparent_spacer.gif" class="ms-crm-ImageStrip-field_change_indicator" alt=""></span><span id="zzz_entity_warnSpan" class="ms-crm-Inline-WarningIcon" title="" style="display: none;" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true"><img src="/_imgs/imagestrips/transparent_spacer.gif" class="ms-crm-ImageStrip-inlineedit_warning" alt="Error" id="zzz_entity_warn"><div id="zzz_entity_w" class="ms-crm-Hidden-NoBehavior"></div></span>
</div>
```

It is also important to note that I also have the following javascript executed onChange of this field. However, this code doesn't seem to ever get executed because unable to select option set field:

```
function OnChangeOfEntity(executionContext) {
    debugger;
    var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
    var optionSetField = formContext.getAttribute("zzz_entity");

    if (optionSetField) {
        // Register an event handler for the OnChange event
        optionSetField.addOnChange(function () {
            // Use getValue to get the selected value
            var selectedValue = optionSetField.getValue();

            if (selectedValue != null) {
                // Log the selected value
                console.log("Selected Entity Value: " + selectedValue);

                // Get the text using the getText() method
                var selectedText = optionSetField.getText();

                // Log the selected text
                console.log("Selected Entity Text: " + selectedText);

                // Call the function to get entity names
                GetEntityCollectionName(selectedText)
                    .then(function (entityCollectionName) {
                        // Work with entityCollectionName
                        formContext.getAttribute("zzz_entityCollection").setValue(entityCollectionName);
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.error(error);
                    });
            } else {
                console.log("No option selected in the jso_entity field.");
                // Handle the case when no option is selected.
            }
        });
    }
}


function GetEntityCollectionName(entityName) {
    debugger;
    var entityName = entityName;
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("GET", Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext().getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.0/EntityDefinitions?$select=LogicalName,CollectionName&$filter=LogicalName eq '" + entityName + "'", true);
        req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
        req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
        req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState === 4) {
                req.onreadystatechange = null;
                if (this.status === 200) {
                    var results = JSON.parse(this.response);
                    if (results.value.length > 0) {
                        var entityCollectionName = results.value[0].CollectionName;
                        resolve(entityCollectionName);
                    } else {
                        reject(new Error('Entity not found.'));
                    }
                } else {
                    reject(new Error('Request failed with status: ' + this.status + ', Status Text: ' + this.statusText));
                }
            }
        };
        req.send();
    });
}
```

**EDIT:**

I have also modified the code to only return 1 result rather than the ~1000 it initially returns. I am still seeing the same behavior with onlly 1 result being returned.

Regards.

Comment: Does this render to html? What does the rendered source code look like?

Comment: What code do you have, linked to the options?

Comment: @mykaf yes it is rendering to html. the html is long so can't post in comment will edit question to add

Comment: @MikeB there is also javascript performed onChange of this field. I will add to question in a moment.

Comment: The html for the select is so long? You only need to post enough to recreate the problem.

Comment: In that case, open "Dev Tools" and see whether or not onChange is firing, and let us know what you see

Comment: @mykaf there is like 1000 different option set values. I've limited the values to shorten. Updated the question with my edit; I'm not the "strongest" web dev, so apologies for not having the immediate insight to only provide the relevant html.

Comment: @MikeB added the javascript for onChange of this field to the question. Please note that this onChange code doesn't even get executed and the onChange isn't even recognized.

Comment: What is `optionSetField` if you log it? I don't see anything with attribute `zzz_entity`

Comment: @mykaf pardon my ignorance, may you elaborate on "What is optionSetField if you log it? I don't see anything with attribute zzz_entity" .please note this previously was working fine. this was produced for a client demo several weeks ago. now it's being built out. i don't know what has changed.

Comment: In your code, you have `var optionSetField = formContext.getAttribute("zzz_entity");`. Add `console.log(optionSetField)`; what is the output? And there is nothing the html you have shraed here that has an attribute of `zzz_entity`. Lots with that string as a id or data-attribute value, but no attributes with that name.

Comment: logged the `optionSetField`: "`optionSetField:  [object Object]`".....`zzz_entity` in the html is on the very first line:  "`<div id="zzz_entity" data-attributename="zzz_entity"`"

Comment: Is that div what's actually being logged? Because that div does not have an attribute called `zzz_entity`.  Is `addOnChange()` part of the dynamics library?

Comment: @mykaf yes, addOnChange is part of Dynamics library. I also limited the filter to only bring back and populate only 1 result (thought maybe the ~1000 bring brought back might of been a problem). However, still same issue with 1 result being populated.

Comment: @mykaf `zzz_entity` is the logical name of the option set.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256560/discussion-between-mykaf-and-j-s-orris).

Answer (score 2):

On Dynamics CRM / Dynamics 365 CE / Power Apps model-driven app, the options of a Choice (OptionSet) attribute must be always the one defined inside the attribute.

Example: inside the attribute definition you have A = 1, B = 2, C = 3.
You can add dynamically D = 4 (by the JS you used, or change the labels) but you will not be able to save the value if it is outside the attribute definition.

Comment: Thanks Guido.  I did  get the drop down to work in the context of being able to select an option. The issue was in fact that my custom entity was not packaged in a UI app. However, you are in fact correct that to be able to save, these values already have to exist in the option set. If not, you will get an "index out of range" error. Because the entities will be dynamic per org (solution to be sold on app store). I had to pivot away from the option set and use a lookup field. If you update your answer to add the issue was web client vs UI Ill accept the answer as what you stated is adds value.

Comment: @J.S.Orris my answer has no reference to your specific issue. If you wish you can write your own answer with the solution and mark that one as accepted.